# trigger build tasks in visual studio and tfs build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a c# solution with multiple projects. I have a .sln file I build the solution with in VS2012.

I am looking to set up TFS Build and want to include some custom msbuild actions, such as running stylecop and fxcop rules. I want these tasks to fire when building the solution locally and within tfs build.

I have looked at creating a .proj file for the solution. However, I am not sure how this can be setup locally and to run the tasks locally.

What is the correct setup for tasks to be run within tfs build and visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is to set the flag "Enable Code Analysis on Build" in the project settings "Code Analysis". More on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668977.aspx).

I suppose that running StyleCop is better fitted in the IDE (check [R#](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)) or the VCS (check [SVNStyleCop](https://svnstylecop.codeplex.com/)) on commit. I am not sure if the same exists for GIT or other repositories.